# How do I Make my Macro for Microsoft Word Produce Multiple Documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that I have been working on, it takes data from another program and then "prints" all of the data into a Word Document. Which is fine, but I would like to have the macro create multiple documents.

I have an example of another macro that a colleague of mine has written that does such a thing, but for different information to what I am working with.

Could someone please help me figure out how to get that same functionality into MY macro?

The example macro with multiple documents working:

**This is the macro that already works, that a colleague made:**

```
Sub state()
Dim strTempF41 As String
Dim strDateType As String
Dim strDate As String
Dim strPolicyType As String
Dim transNoStarts As Integer
Dim individualStatements, strText As String
Dim numStatements, msgResponse As Integer
Dim intPosition As Integer


g_strDirectoryPolicy = g_strUserNetDrive
g_strFilenameDestination = "state.doc"
g_strDest = g_strDirectoryPolicy & g_strFilenameDestination
g_strFilenameSource = g_strCompanyPrefix & "_dum_state.doc"
g_strSource = g_strDummyDir & g_strFilenameSource

If g_arrFNumbers(13) = "T" Then
    g_strSource = chkDotDoc(g_arrFNumbers(14) & ".doc")
    g_strFilenameSource = chkDotDoc(g_arrFNumbers(14) & ".doc")
        Do
            intPosition = InStr(1, g_strFilenameSource, "\")
            If (intPosition > 0) Then
                g_strFilenameSource = Mid$(g_strFilenameSource, intPosition + 1)
            End If
        Loop Until intPosition = 0
End If

'URM7370 This does the merge to individual statements, but it has been agreed that this will not be used yet
' Changes need to be added to form to have a Y/N flag in F21

If individualStatementsEnabled = True Then
    individualStatements = "Y"      'set to g_arrFNumbers(21)
    g_arrFNumbers(21) = "Y"
Else
    individualStatements = "N"
    g_arrFNumbers(21) = "N"
End If

g_LastDocument = False

g_lastPartner = ""
g_LastPartnerRecord = 0
numStatements = 0
If g_arrFNumbers(21) <> "Y" Then
    g_LastDocument = True
End If

    Do
        If fileDoesExist(g_strSource) Then
            Documents.Open fileName:=g_strSource, READONLY:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=True, PasswordDocument:="", _
            PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto
        Else
            eventMsg ("eventMsg 101 state:" & vbCrLf & "File " & g_strSource & " does not exist.")
        End If

        numStatements = numStatements + 1
        Merge

        'This saves the file as a PDF and then will send an email (with the doc file attached)
        'Will never go throgh this code at the moment as option hasn't been released
        If individualStatements = "Y" Then
            'If 2010 or above, save as PDF
            If g_strWordVers = "2010" Or g_strWordVers = "2013" Or g_strWordVers = "Post 2013" Then
                g_strFilenameDestination = "state_" & g_lastPartner & ".pdf"
                g_strDest = g_strDirectoryPolicy & g_strFilenameDestination
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 fileName:=g_strDest, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF

                        'eventMsg ("eventMsg 110 state: Request to send email found in PC.CSV for PROFSCHED file.")
                        'Dim strEmail As String
                        'Dim strCompany As String
                        'Dim strCopyFile As String
                        'strEmail = g_arrFNumbers(22)
                        'strCompany = g_arrFNumbers(1)
                        'strCopyFile = g_strDest

                        'strText = "Do you wish to send an email with the statement for " & g_lastPartner
                        'If MsgBox(strText, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                        '    eventMsg ("eventMsg 113 state: Attempting to send email directly to " & strEmail)
                        '    ActiveDocument.SendMail
                        '    eventMsg ("eventMsg 114 state: Email request complete.")
                        'End If
                End If
                'Keep the documents open for the moment - may need to look again if too may open
               'ActiveDocument.Close

        End If

        If g_LastDocument = True Then
            eventMsg ("eventMsg 103 state: All statements completed, total  " & numStatements)
            Exit Do
        Else
            g_arrFNumbers(21) = individualStatements
            LoadPCCSV ("pc.csv")
            g_arrFNumbers(21) = individualStatements
            eventMsg ("eventMsg 102 state: Merge for partner " & g_lastPartner)
        End If

    Loop Until g_LastDocument = True    'last record is false so must be more partners


    'ActiveDocument.Saved = True
    If individualStatements = "Y" Then
        strText = "All statements complete, total " & numStatements
        MsgBox strText, vbOKOnly
    End If


    MakeWordVisible
    MacroFinish

    End

End Sub
```

**This is the macro that I need help with:**

```
    Sub closings()
Dim strFileToInsert As String

g_strFilenameDestination = "closings" & g_arrFNumbers(7)
g_strDest = g_strDirectoryPolicy & g_strFilenameDestination & ".doc"

g_strFilenameSource = g_strCompanyPrefix & "_dum_closings.doc"
g_strSource = g_strDummyDir & g_strFilenameSource

eventMsg ("eventMsg 101 closings: Source = " & g_strSource & ", destination = " & g_strDest)

If g_arrFNumbers(13) = "C" Then
    deleteFile (g_strDest)

    If fileDoesExist(g_strSource) Then
        Documents.Open fileName:=g_strSource, ConfirmConversions:=False, READONLY:=False, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=True, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
            WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto
    Else
        displayErr "eventMsg 102 closings: File " & g_strSource & " does not exist.", "C", True
    End If

    If g_arrFNumbers(16) <> "" Then
        eventMsg ("eventMsg 103 closings: Inserting " & g_arrFNumbers(16))

        'Navigate to fill field f31 (Transaction) ready for insertion..
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

        findText ("f31")
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

        strFileToInsert = g_strDirectoryWP & g_arrFNumbers(16)
        If fileDoesExist(strFileToInsert) Then
            Selection.InsertFile fileName:=strFileToInsert, Range:="", Link:=False, Attachment:=False
        Else
            displayErr "eventMsg 104 closings: File " & strFileToInsert & " does not exist.", "C", True
        End If
    End If

    If g_arrFNumbers(17) <> "" Then
        eventMsg ("eventMsg 105 closings: Inserting " & g_arrFNumbers(17))
        GoToEnd
        strFileToInsert = g_strUserNetDrive & g_arrFNumbers(17)

        If fileDoesExist(strFileToInsert) Then
            Selection.InsertFile fileName:=strFileToInsert, Range:="", Link:=False, Attachment:=False
        Else
            displayErr "eventMsg 106 closings: File " & strFileToInsert & " does not exist.", "C", True
        End If
    End If

    eventMsg ("eventMsg 107 closings: Merging to " & g_strDest)

    'This does the merge... to g_strDest
    Merge

    GoToStart
    ActiveDocument.Saved = True

End If

If g_arrFNumbers(13) = "E" Then

    'Open the g_strDest file..
    If fileDoesExist(g_strDest) Then
        Documents.Open fileName:=g_strDest, READONLY:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", _
            PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
            Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto
    Else
        displayErr "eventMsg 108 closings: File " & g_strDest & " does not exist.", "E", True
    End If
End If

MakeWordVisible
MacroFinish
End

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was just doing it wrong. All I needed to do was copy and paste the functionality from the first macro into the second and change a few key words.

Apologies if this question wasted anybody's time.

Edit: I am still new to this line of work, and am bound to make mistakes, so thank you to Sam for being patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a Document variable:

```
Dim MyDoc as Document
```

Then when you open your document, make sure you use that variable:

```
Set MyDoc = Documents.Open...
```

Then replace every ActiveDocument with MyDoc. Now you have the possibility to handle more documents at the same time (by creating more document variables), while also making it more robust.
Next thing to remove is Selection.

Comment: If you look at the first code block I posted with the macro that already works (created by a colleague), you will notice that there is no Document variable in there, and yet it works. Unfortunately, the macro is run from an external program, and then produces the document required. But I want it to create multiple documents and not just one, using a similar method to the first code-block I posted.

Comment: That might be the case, but as long as you rely on ActiveDocument and Selection, you are in a place where it is hard to know exactly what those return at any given moment and what data you are working with.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over this, as it is the way my Manager and Employer want me to do it. This macro is one of many in a long list all contained within "normal.dotm"

Comment: Then I suggest that you put a breakpoint somewhere near the top and step through the code. Both in yours and in the other. Compare what is happening.

Comment: I will take another look then. What information should I try to come back with?

Comment: I think you'll find the answer for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have tried to look back at the code and my question to see how I can give better information, but I honestly can't. I'm still rather new to this. I really do appreciate the help though.